# What is the difference between monkey patching and decorators in python?

Tags: python, decorator, monkeypatching

In python, decorators and monkey patching looks similar, what exactly the difference between monkey patching and decorators.

Comment: They are not similar.  Can you show examples that make you think it is similar?

Answer (score 1):

Patching involves modifying an existing *object*. (That object could be a module, for example when you use `unittest.mock` to make some name in the module's global namespace refer to a different value.)

Decorator syntax is syntactic sugar for a function call and subsequent (re)assignment to a *name*. You can write

```
@foo
def bar():
    ...
```

instead of the more verbose, repetitive

```
def bar():
    ...

bar = foo(bar)
```

`foo` might patch `bar` at runtime, but decorators aren't *required* to patch anything (and often don't, instead creating a new object that wraps the previous object in some way).

For example, a patching decorator:

```
def foo(f):
    f.thing = 0
    return f
```

vs a non-patching decorator:

```
def foo(f):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Calling the function")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

The first one would modify the function referenced by `bar` directly. The second one simply makes the name `bar` refer to a new function that has its own reference (`f`) to the original, unmodified `bar`.

---

One might argue that the decorator modifies the current module, and should thus count as monkey patching. However, there's a critical distinction: the module doesn't actually *exist* yet when the decorator is applied. The contents of a file are first evaluated to produce a set of names, which are *then* used to create the `module` object having those names as attributes.